# Rails uses different encoding for 'puts' vs 'return'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, encoding

I have a Rails method that ends like this:

```
puts encrypted
return encrypted
```

Console outputs:

```
#?$???z???e7Bw?1I?F???????s?w
=> "#\x9A$\xB1\xBA\xF4z\x8F\x97\xECe\a7Bw\xE01I\xEDF\xA6\xBE\xEA\xE0\xFC\xF6\xB9\x1Cs\x00\xC0w\x14"
```

1. Why do these results look different when output in the same place and without any encode/decode instructions?
2. How can I get Rails to output the longer version when I call `puts encrypted`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IRB calls `inspect` on its values before dumping them in order to expose codes that might get output as just `?` or worse, in this kind of situations.

Try `p encrypted`, then try `puts encrypted.inspect`.

Comment: Both of those work. Is it better to use one vs. the other?

Comment: `p` is shorter, unless you are using IRB, when just `encrypted` works to show you the `.inspect` version. But "better" for what? debugging?

Comment: Yes, mainly for debugging. Probably will eventually be kept inside `logger.debug`.